# Is there an example on ManageBuyOfferResult?

Tags: manageofferoperation

When creating a new buy offer, one sets `OfferID` to 0 in `txnbuild.ManageBuyOffer` operation. I would expect `OfferID` for a newly created offer to be returned in `ManageBuyOfferResult`, but I can't figure out how to get a hold on the result. What is it that I am missing? Is there an example on how `ManageBuyOfferResult` is supposed to be used? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it is all in the (Go) code. For example:

```
var v xdr.TransactionResult
opResult := (*(*v.Result.Results)[0].Tr).ManageBuyOfferResult
```

The ultimate documentation is code!